# Confused by R coding example in Hyndman's FPP, Ch 6.2

Tags: r

Chapt. 6.2 of Hyndman's book, "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" contains the following text and example R code:

> For example, we might take a moving average of order 4, and then apply
> another moving average of order 2 to the results. In the following
> table, this has been done for the first few years of the Australian
> quarterly beer production data.
>
> ```
> beer2 <- window(ausbeer,start=1992)
> ma4 <- ma(beer2, order=4, centre=FALSE)
> ma2x4 <- ma(beer2, order=4, centre=TRUE)
> ```

I'm confused over this sample code. Does the sample R code match what the text says? The sample code calls the ma() function twice, passing in the same data each time. How does this create a moving average of a moving average. Doesn't this just create 2 simple moving averages on the same data?

In order to do what the text claims, shouldn't the sample code look like this:

```
beer2 <- window(ausbeer,start=1992)
ma4 <- ma(beer2, order=4, centre=FALSE)
ma2x4 <- ma(ma4, order=4, centre=TRUE)
```

Thank you for your kind assistance in this matter.

- DF

Comment: Is this the book you are talking about? https://otexts.com/fpp3/ I can't seem to find that code in section 6.2

Comment: It's in https://otexts.com/fpp2/

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there are an fpp3 out there on otexts.com. We are using fpp2 as Suren pointed to:  https://otexts.com/fpp2/moving-averages.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a MA of order 4 followed by a MA of order 2, so the last line should be `ma2x4 <- ma(ma4, order=2, centre=FALSE)`. You'd get the exact result in the book with `center = FALSE`.

```
> ma(ma4, order=2, centre=TRUE)
         Qtr1     Qtr2     Qtr3     Qtr4
1992       NA       NA 450.0625 450.1875
1993 448.3750 446.2500 444.5000 441.3125
1994 441.6250 443.3750 443.3750 444.8750
1995 445.0000 442.1250 438.6875 435.2500
1996 431.5625 430.2500 432.3125 434.2500
```

or

```
> ma(ma4, order=2, centre=FALSE)
        Qtr1    Qtr2    Qtr3    Qtr4
1992      NA 450.000 450.125 450.250
1993 446.500 446.000 443.000 439.625
1994 443.625 443.125 443.625 446.125
1995 443.875 440.375 437.000 433.500
```

Edit

Following is the order of R statements.

```
beer2 <- window(ausbeer,start=1992)
ma4 <- ma(beer2, order=4, centre=FALSE)
ma2x4 <- ma(ma4, order=2, centre=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. It looks sort of like you are agreeing with me that there is an inconsistency between the code and the text explaining the code.

I'm just trying to clarify that the code as it is in the book isn't doing what he claims. It's not passing in the RESULTS of the prior call but rather the same data (beer2) as the prior call ... so it's not going to produce any "moving average of a moving average" ... am I correct in this?

Comment: And yes, I fully undestood that the ORDER of the 2nd call also needed to change ... about 3 seconds after I submitted question.

But my main confusion is over the first parameter ... it should be ma4. I think we agree on  this, right?

Comment: I edited the answer addressing your questions in the comments.  Yes, in the last line it uses the time series `ma4` as the input in producing `ma2x4`.